# How to give content view in swiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to run some code but it has content view as parameter , I am not sure how to resolve this. Suggest solution for same

[image]

```
struct ContentView<Content: View>: View {
    @Binding var isOpen: Bool

    let maxHeight: CGFloat
    let minHeight: CGFloat
    let content: Content

    @GestureState private var translation: CGFloat = 0
```

[image]

Comment: Why have you declared it as `ContentView<Content: View>`?

Comment: just delete the `<Content: View>`

Answer (score 2):

Here is what you need, depending on your question:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct YourApp: App {
    
    @State private var isOpen: Bool = false
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView(isOpen: $isOpen, maxHeight: 200, minHeight: 50, content: Text("Hello, world!"))
        }
    }
}


struct ContentView<Content: View>: View {
    @Binding var isOpen: Bool

    let maxHeight: CGFloat
    let minHeight: CGFloat
    let content: Content

    @GestureState private var translation: CGFloat = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        content
    }
    
}
```